# Users database design for DynamoDB and fast performance search with Cloudsearch

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb, database-schema, amazon-cloudsearch, nosql

I'm studying how to use DynamoDB and Cloudsearch for my application. I don't understand a couple of things about database schema for DynamoDB. Considering this schema:

**USERS table**

```
{
   "id_users"(PI): <number>,
   "created": <string>,
   "email" (GSI): <string>,
   "firstname": <string>,
   "lastname": <string>
   "password"(GSI): <string>,
   "verified": <boolean>,
   "category": <string>,
   "colors": <array of strings>, // list of favourite colors of the users (it's an example)
   "locale": <string>,
   "user_location": {    //GeoJSON structure
       "type": <string> ex. "location",
       "geometry": {
          "type": <string> ex. "Point",
          "coordinates": [ <number> ex. 125.6, <number> 10.1]
       },
       "properties": {
           "city": <string>,
           "country": <string>
       }
   },
   "accounts": [ 
          {
           "type": <string>, // ex. "facebook"
           "ID": <number>, // ex. 23248323243473743
           "access_token": <string>,
           "profile_url": <string>
          },
          {
           "type": <string>, // ex. "google"
           "ID": <number>, // ex. 23248323243473743
           "access_token": <string>,
           "profile_url": <string>
          }
     ]
}
```

It's a part of the complete schema.

So, 
the path of application are `myurl.com/users/{:id_users}`.

I need to search active users and/or within a radius, or country and who likes one or plus colours (an example). I've read than I can't add indexes inside a deeper level than first of the tree, and the index can be only string, integer or binary. In addition, Cloudsearch has more types of index, this is perfect for `"colours"` and `"verified"`, but I can't add "deep" index for `"coordinates"`. 
I could move the coordinates on first level like this:

```
location_coordinates:  [ <number> ex. 125.6, <number> 10.1],
location_city: <string>,
location_country: <string>,
```

but it isn't "elegant". I could create an external table for user locations, but that I could lose all the advantages for a document database and I can't retrieve/read all datas with one call when a user visits a profile.

I have to modify my database schema? How?

Who cares the elegance, I have to put the coordinates on first level?

The fact that there isn't a index associate at `"coordinates"` item, it have a negative impact on performance? Obviously, When I search users with a geo query.

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the help,
Alessandro.

Comment: You need to use cloud search to do the search. Add all the fields you want to search as index parameters, There are also latlon fields to help with the geo searching. Once you retrieve the results you can pull the required results by id from dynamodb. Dynamo and Cloud search are not linked to each other automatically, you need to create a separate cloud search domain and make sure any update to dynamoDB is updated to cloud search using DynamoStreams and Lambda.

Comment: There is no need of a deep index, When there is an update to a dynamoDB document, the dynamo stream will invoke a lambda function. The lambda function will then transform the data and update cloud search. You can convert your location to a latlon field and update cloud search here to do the geo search.

Comment: ah, I understood! Thanks for the explaination :) Answer my question instead of add a comment, so I can mark the flag "answered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use cloud search to do the search. Add all the fields you want to search as index parameters, There are also latlon fields to help with the geo searching. Cloud search will return the id of the object along with the indexed fields if any of the documents match your search query. Once you retrieve the results from cloud search you can fetch the required documents from dynamoDB using the id.

Dynamo and Cloud search are not linked to each other automatically, you need to create a separate cloud search domain and make sure any update to dynamoDB is updated to cloud search using DynamoStreams and Lambda.

There is no need of a deep index, When there is an update to a dynamoDB document, the dynamo stream will invoke a lambda function. The lambda function will then transform the data and update cloud search. You can convert your location to a latlon field and update cloud search here to do the geo search.